# asp.net Detail Model logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a programm logic problem..

Ok, let's start.

I have 2 classes in a model.

```
namespace Korbball.Models
{
public class Clubs
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class ClubDetails : Clubs
{
    public string website { get; set; }
    public string banner { get; set; }
}
```

}

In a first step, i will call an overview of all Clubs with the entries of the Club Class.
If i click on a Club, there is a link to -> Website/Clubs/Details/Id

Now, i will show on this view all the data from Clubs and ClubDetails.

The Data for this is stored on a database.

```
    private static List<Clubs> clubs = new List<Clubs>();
    KorbballEntities db = new KorbballEntities();

    public KorbballRepository()
    {
        var clubsdata = db.Korbball_Clubs.ToArray();
        foreach (var c in clubsdata)
        {
            clubs.Add(new Clubs { id = c.ClubId, name = c.Name, state = c.State });
        }
    }
```

So i get the Data for ONLY the club information.
For Details, should i generate a new LIST with all the informations?

Hope anybody know what i mean...can't declare it much better..

thanks!

Update:
Ok, i think the problem is, that i cant find someone who can teach me the mvc logic =D

I have many clubs. This clubs has basic informations (name,id,state)

This clubs have also detailed informations like description,banner,website etc.

I made a ModelClass

ClubModel.cs

```
 public class Clubs
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public string state { get; set; }
public string description { get; set; }
}

public class ClubDetails : Clubs
{
public string website { get; set; }
public string banner { get; set; }
}
```

I will show a list of all Clubs with the basic informations with site/Clubs

If i go to the detailed view, Clubs/Details/Id i will show all the information(Basic + detailed)

Your solution seems to be cool. I cant find any ideas on the internet how to build the "best practice" method on such a situation.

Comment: Use `ClubDetails` everywhere you'd normally use `Clubs` because the former inherits from the latter, and the latter does not know about the extra properties of the former.

Answer (score 0):

Is the relationship between Club and Details one-to-one?  It sounds like it based on how you described everything but it doesn't make as much sense because like someone mentioned you inherited from Club, so you could just load Club_Details and you'll automatically get Club columns.

If your relationship were one-to-many the easiest way is to build the **association** into your model (foreign key relationship on the database) and then use the "Include" to tell Entity Framework that you want associated entities.  I put this together quickly so syntax may not be perfect the basic idea is to look into the "Include".

This logic is flawed because it is loading many clubs and then loading club details, you'd want to fix that.

```
private static List<Clubs> clubs = new List<Clubs>();
private List<Club_Details> clubDetails = new List<Club_Details>();
// make a view model class that contains club and club details (one to many)
private ClubData clubdata = new ClubData();

public KorbballRepository()
{
    var clubsdata = db.Clubs.Include("Club_Details").ToArray();
    foreach (var c in clubsdata)
    {
        clubs.Add(new Clubs { id = c.ClubId, name = c.Name, state = c.State });

        /* sample of how to reference the Included entities use the association name
           of Club_Details if it were a one to many relationship, ideally you
           would create a view  model or something with the two classes defined
           and one club and list of club details, then define a list of the view
           model for all Clubs */

         clubDetails = new List<Club_Details>();

         foreach (var d in c.Club_Details)
         { 
              clubDetails.Add(new Club_Details { 
                   website = d.website.ToString(), 
                   banner = d.banner.ToString() 
               });;
          }

    /* load the data to the view model class and loop again */
    }

}
```

Comment: wow, thank you for the fast answer...

i'll try to fix it. maybe you can have a look on it after i do that.

regards

Comment: You are welcome. I found a cleaner example of a one-to-many relationship and the concept of using "Include" for you here:  http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/28/mvcscaffolding-one-to-many-relationships/   HTH